# jQuery is not recognising dynamic html classes/ids

Tags: jquery, dynamic, lightbox, dynamic-html

I'm creating a YouTube playlist gallery, I'm trying to get the thumbnails to open a lightbox which then displays the video iframe.

The lightbox wont work with my dynamic html, it seems like its not recognising the classes.

I'm fairly new to jQuery so any help or hints would be appreciated!

The lightbox code

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("a#show-panel").click(function(){  
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);  
  })  
  $("a#close-panel").click(function(){  
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);  
 })  
})
```

Calling in the YouTube data to create dynamic html

```
function getVideoHtml(video)
{

title =  video.title.$t;
url =  video.content.src;
views =  video.yt$statistics.viewCount;
dateCreated = video.published.$t;
videoId =  video.media$group.yt$videoid.$t;
//console.log(videoId);
videoThumb = video.media$group.media$thumbnail.url;
//console.log(videoThumb);
videoHtml = "<div> \
 <a id=\"show-panel\" href=\"#\"> \
 <img src=\"http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+videoId+"/mqdefault.jpg\"/> </a> \
   <div id=\"lightbox-panel\"><h2>"+title+"</h2> <iframe id=\"ytplayer"+videoId+"\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"300\" height=\"250\" \
  src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+videoId+"?autoplay=0&origin=http://example.com\" \
  frameborder=\"0\"/> \
  <p align=\"center\"><a id=\"close-panel\" href=\"#\">Close this window</a></p> \
 </div> \
    </div>\
    <div class=\"lightbox\"></div> \
<p>"+title+"</p> \
<p>views:"+views+"</p> \
<p>date created: "+dateCreated+"</p> \
</div>";
return videoHtml;
}
```

Comment: jQuery will only attached event handlers to elements that exist at the time the listener is attached. You need to attach the listener to a parent element that's common for all of them so that the click event can bubble up

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way. You need to bind the links using `on()`. Now if you are creating dynamic links where there might be multiple on the same page, I would use a class selector because ID's are unique.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(document).on("click","a#show-panel",function(){  
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);  
  })  
  $(document).on("click","a#close-panel",function(){  
    $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);  
 })  
})
```